# How to omit a value in a select lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, select, lambda

I want to make a simple CSV parser. It should go through a list of comma separated values and put them in a `IList<int>`. The values are expected to be integer numbers. In case a value is not parseable, I just want to omit it.

This is the code I have so far:

```
csv.Split(',').Select(item =>
{
    int parsed;
    if (int.TryParse(item, out parsed))
    {
        return parsed;
    }
    continue; //is not allowed here
}).ToList();
```

However, the use of `continue` is (of course) not allowed here. **How to omit a value in my select implementation?**

Note: Of course could I use a foreach or a LINQ expression, but I wonder how to do it with a lambda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ExtractInt32(this IEnumerable<string> values) {
    foreach(var s in values) {
        int i;
        if(int.TryParse(s, out i)) yield return i;
    }
}
```

then:

```
var vals = csv.Split(',').ExtractInt32().ToList();
```

The nice things here:

- avoids magic "sentinal" numbers (like `int.MinValue`)
- avoids a separate and disconnected "it is valid" / "parse" step (so no duplication)

Comment: Actually, on second thought, this is the best answer in my opinion.

Comment: @Laurant the good thing about "magic" is that you can look behind the curtain and see how the trick is done. IIRC Jon's book "C# in Depth", chapter 6, covers this in exquisite detail. And that chapter may still be free (it was a demo chapter for a long while).

Comment: Although no lambda is used, a my first intention was, this is the most elegant solution. Thanks @MarcGravell

Comment: @Marcel sometimes, if the question is "what is the best hammer to drive screws?", the most appropriate answer involves a screw-driver instead.

Answer (score 2):

`Select` transforms a value. It doesn't filter. `Where` is doing that:

```
csv.Split(',')
   .Select(item =>
           {
               int parsed;
               return new { IsNumber = int.TryParse(item, out parsed), 
                            Value = parsed };
           })
   .Where(x => x.IsNumber)
   .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Additionally, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910867/572644) for a clever, short way of doing it. Please note that the meaning of "clever" isn't entirely positive here.

Comment: Your solution should work, however, the usage of a new anonymous type embarasses me. This seems to be much more expensive than the foreach alternative.

Comment: @Marcel: Indeed. I would never use code like this. I would go with a loop here. But you wanted to do it in LINQ (see your last sentence).

Comment: If one dislikes anonymous types, you can use a nullable type, as in `.Select(item => { int parsed; return int.TryParse(item, out parsed) ? parsed : (int?)null; })`. Probably not faster than the anonymous type, though. Your linked answer where you use "closure" in a shocking way, fascinates.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: The important point of the other answer actually is the deferred nature of LINQ to objects. Good idea with the nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have three options:

1. Use `SelectMany` instead which will allow you to return as empty enumerable for elements you wish to omit (and an enumerable of length 1 otherwise).
2. Use an int value you are sure won't be in the set (e.g. `-1`) to represent 'omitted' and filter them out afterwards. This approach is fragile as you may pick a value that subsequently appears in the set which will result in a subtle bug. (You could mitigate this by using a larger data type, e.g. `long` and picking a value outside the range of `int` but then you will need to convert back to `int` subsequently.)
3. Use `Nullable<int>` (`int?`) instead and filter out the `null` values afterwards.

1:

```
csv.Split(',').SelectMany(item =>
    {
        int parsed;
        if (int.TryParse(item, out parsed))
        {
            return new[] {parsed};
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<int>();   
    }
```

3:

```
csv.Split(',').Select(item =>
    {
        int parsed;
        if (int.TryParse(item, out parsed))
        {
            return (int?) parsed;
        }

        return (int?) null;
     }
    .Where(item => item.HasValue)
    .Select(item => item.Value);
```

Comment: Good idea, but still makes this whole thing more complex than I think should be possible, either way.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to return some default value and then skip it.

```
errorInt = int.MinValue;
csv.Split(',').Select(item =>
{
    int parsed;
    if (int.TryParse(item, out parsed))
    {
        return parsed;
    }
    else
    {
        return errorInt;
    }

}).Where(val => val != errorInt).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use `Where` on array and only then select proper ints

```
csv.Split(',')
    .Where(item => 
          { 
              int parsed; 
              return int.TryParse(item, out parsed); 
          })
    .Select(item => Convert.ToInt32(item));
```

Comment: Er, wouldn't char working only on chars, not a string? My nubmers can have multiple digits.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int dummy;
sv.Split(',').Where(c => int.TryParse(c,out dummy)).Select(c => int.Parse(c));
```

The `int.TryParse(..)` just checks if it is a valid string to be translated into an int. The out parameter is just ignored - we cont need it.

We know that only those string values that "makes-it" to the `Select()` are values that can be  safetly parsed as int's.

Comment: A nice idea. But what tastes bad is calling the parse method twice, when one call can give me all information I need.

Comment: I wouldn't mind :) there has to be a really huge amount of data for it to matter. If that is the case - perhaps a `Parallel.ForEach()` would be the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just use:

```
csv.Split(',').Where(item => isValid(item)).Select(item => TransformationExpression(item));
```

or,

```
csv.Split(',').Select(item => ReturnsDummyValueIfInvalid(item)).Where(item => item != DummyValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int TempInt;
List<int> StuffIWant = csv.Split(',').Where(item => int.TryParse(item, TempInt)).ToList();
```

Comment: That gives you a `List<string>` - it doesn't keep the parsed values. Also, it won't compile without an `out`.

Comment: Good spot @MarcGravell - I missed the IList<int> bit in the Question.